# "The Old Gods died" - how did Steppenwolf know that?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, justice-league-2017

In *Justice League* (2017), Steppenwolf figures out that Wonder Woman has "the power of the Old Gods". He then derisively remarks:

> The Old Gods died.

But I don't see how he can know that. We see the Old Gods (including Ares) fighting against Steppenwolf's original invasion, so we know that it took place *before* Ares killed them all. It's possible that some of them died during Steppenwolf's invasion, but he seems to be aware that they're *all* now dead.

**How does Steppenwolf know this?** Did he just deduce it from their absence? Or is this a continuity error?

Comment: They were all killed during the War of the Gods apart from Ares who was eventually killed by Wonder Woman. As for how Steppenwolf knows, I'm not sure.

Comment: Perhaps it was  in the intergalictic news....seems like a big enough story.

Comment: Well, he was up-to-date for all current events including Superman's death . Him knowing about the Old Gods is quite natural then.

Comment: @Shreedhar You got me thinking, and I think I've worked it out now... I'll write up an answer.

Comment: You underestimated Darkseid..

Comment: Is it possible (having not seen the movie yet... I'm slow) that he's referring to the Old Gods of the First World from the comics, which (supposedly) died out long before even Darkseid existed?  Darkseid is a New God, named in relation to that particular set of Old Gods.  The destruction of the Old Gods is what actually caused the creation of Earth's pantheons (as well as that of other planets).  The destruction of their world created the twin planets of Apokalypse and New Genesis, the inhabitants of which would become the New Gods over time.

http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Old_Gods

Comment: @DuckPuppy Given that he states immediately beforehand that Wonder Woman has "the power of the Old Gods", it's safe to assume he's referring specifically to Zeus and co.

Comment: I think that the Earth pantheons do predate the New Gods, so the naming at least works.  Plus, Darkseid and Co are, well, gods (at least compared to us puny mortal creatures), so I'd chalk it up keeping up with what's going on with the competition.  I'm sure that DC movies are going to strip down the New Gods/Fourth World stuff to simplify it for the audiences.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

@Shreedhar pointed out in the comments that Steppenwolf seems to be generally up-to-speed with events on Earth, up to and including Superman's arrival and death. I wondered how this could be, and that's when I remembered: **Steppenwolf was sending out Parademons to scout Earth.** We see Batman tracking one at the start of the film.

The most logical explanation, then, is that one of the Parademon scouts learned of the Old Gods' deaths, and relayed that information to Steppenwolf. Of course, that raises the question of how the *Parademon* found out, but that's something we probably can't answer.

Comment: +1 for mentioning Batman's encounter with the Parademon. I had totally forgotten about that

Comment: I don't know much about Parademons... but I would argue that the Parademon found out due to the lack of worship and decay of the old temples and such. Even if the Parademon never spoke to anyone and only observed it should easily become obvious that we are no longer worshiping in the same manner as before and all the old monuments and such are falling into decay. As well, given that Superman wasn't around during the age of the Old Gods that should signify that the Parademons have a fair amount of intelligence and did some extended research on what has been happening the last couple millennia.

Comment: @Odin1806 I suppose that's true. He could have meant it in a Nietzsche-esque metaphorical manner, without knowing they really *were* dead.

Comment: @F1Krazy - I think it would be safe to assume he knew they were actually dead. In that scene from the movie when everyone fought Steppenwolf the first time, there were Parademons there. I would think that the Old Gods would have noticed Parademons showing up again and taking them out or something. The fact they didn't I think plays to the idea he knew they were gone as well. Maybe? - Battle isabout a minute in on this clip https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2frgpxNw5UY